# How to send a large matrix to a shader?

Tags: matrix, textures, webgl

I would like to send a matrix bigger than 4*4(mat4) in a vertex shader. I was thinking to put the matrix in a texture and send the texture to the shader instead.

The problem is that I don't know how exactly to do that. 
Can you help me with a basic example on how to set a matrix in a texture and how to get the elements from the texture in the shader?

Here are some parts of my code: 
Having 2 matrices : m1 and m2:

```
r1 = m1.rows,
r2 = m2.rows,
c1 = m1.cols,
c2 = m2.cols,
d1 = m1.data,
d2 = m2.data;
```

Data to be put in the texture :

```
count = Math.max(r1, r2) * Math.max(c1, c2);
var texels = new Float32Array(3 * count); // RGB
        /* same dimensions for both matrices */
        if (r1 == r2 && c1 == c2) {
            /* put m1 in red channel and m2 in green channel */
            var i = 0, index1 = 0, index2 = 0;
            do {
                texels[i++] = d1[index1++];
                texels[i++] = d2[index2++];
                i++; // skip blue channel
            } while (--count);
        } else {
            var index, row = 0, col = 0;
            for (index = 0; index < r1 * c1; index++) {
                texels[index * 3] = d1[index];
            }

            for (index = 0; index < r2 * c2; index++) {
                texels[index * 3 + 1] = d2[index];
            }
        }
```

Making the texture :

```
var texture = gl.createTexture();
gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGB, Math.max(m1.c, m2.c), Math.max(m1.r, m2.r), 0, gl.RGB, gl.FLOAT, texels);

gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);

var sampler = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "usampler");
gl.uniform1i(sampler, 0);
```

Vertex shader :

```
#ifdef GL_ES 
    precision highp float; 
#endif 
attribute vec3 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_texcoord;
varying vec2   vTex;
void main(void)
{
gl_Position = vec4(a_position, 1.0);
vTex = a_texcoord;
}
```

Fragment shader :

```
#ifdef GL_ES 
    precision highp float; 
#endif 
 
   // passed in from the vertex shader. 
    varying vec2      vTex;         // row, column to calculate 
    uniform sampler2D usampler;     
    uniform int       uLength;      
    uniform float     uStepS;       // increment across source texture 
    uniform float     uStepT;       // increment down source texture 
    uniform float     uOutRows;     
    uniform float     uOutCols;     
      
    // sum row r x col c 
    float sumrowcol(float row, float col) { 
        float sum = 0.;             // sum 
        float ss = 0.;              // column on source texture 
        float tt = 0.;              // row on source texture 
        float r = row*uStepT;       // moving texture coordinate 
        float c = col*uStepS;       // moving texture coordinate 
        for (int pos=0; pos<2048; ++pos) { 
            if(pos >= uLength) break; // stop when we multiple a row by a column 
            float m1 = texture2D(usampler,vec2(r,ss)).r; 
            float m2 = texture2D(usampler,vec2(tt,c)).g; 
            sum += (m1*m2); 
            ss += uStepS; 
            tt += uStepT; 
        } 
        return sum; 
    } 
      
   float shift_right (float v, float amt) { 
       v = floor(v) + 0.5; 
       return floor(v / exp2(amt)); 
   }
      
   float shift_left (float v, float amt) { 
       return floor(v * exp2(amt) + 0.5); 
   }
      
   float mask_last (float v, float bits) {
       return mod(v, shift_left(1.0, bits)); 
   }
      
   float extract_bits (float num, float from, float to) { 
       from = floor(from + 0.5); to = floor(to + 0.5); 
       return mask_last(shift_right(num, from), to - from); 
   }
      
   vec4 encode_float (float val) { 
       if (val == 0.0) return vec4(0, 0, 0, 0); 
       float sign = val > 0.0 ? 0.0 : 1.0; 
       val = abs(val); 
       float exponent = floor(log2(val)); 
       float biased_exponent = exponent + 127.0; 
       float fraction = ((val / exp2(exponent)) - 1.0) * 8388608.0; 
       float t = biased_exponent / 2.0; 
       float last_bit_of_biased_exponent = fract(t) * 2.0; 
       float remaining_bits_of_biased_exponent = floor(t); 
       float byte4 = extract_bits(fraction, 0.0, 8.0) / 255.0; 
       float byte3 = extract_bits(fraction, 8.0, 16.0) / 255.0; 
       float byte2 = (last_bit_of_biased_exponent * 128.0 + extract_bits(fraction, 16.0, 23.0)) / 255.0; 
       float byte1 = (sign * 128.0 + remaining_bits_of_biased_exponent) / 255.0; 
       return vec4(byte1, byte2, byte3, byte4); 
    } 
    void main(void) { 
          
        // get the implied row and column from .s and .t of passed texel 
        float col = floor((vTex.s*uOutRows)); 
        float row = floor((vTex.t*uOutCols));    
 
        // sum row x col for the passed pixel 
        float v = sumrowcol(row,col); 
 
        gl_FragColor = encode_float(v); 
    }
```

Comment: Are you using desktop OpenGL or WebGL? Which one you use changes the answer.

Comment: How large does the matrix have to be? Also, remember that passing textures to vertex shaders requires the so-called TVF ([texture vertex fetch](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Texture_Fetch)) capability from a GPU.

Comment: You could do `uniform float m[25]` for a 5x5 matrix.

Comment: @hidefromkgb [which is supported by 98.6% of WebGL supporting devices...](http://webglstats.com/webgl/parameter/MAX_VERTEX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS)

Comment: @Nicol Bolas I am using WebGL.

Comment: @hidefromkgb the dimension of the matrix can vary from case to case. What I want to do is to store the elements of a matrix in the red channel and the elements from another one in the green channel and send the texture to the shader where I want to operate with the values (in my case, multiply them). So in fragment shader I want to take a line from the first matrix and a column from the second one and compute an element in the result matrix.

Comment: Don't forget to execute `texels.position(0)` before using `texImage2D`, or the data won't get sent up as expected * sighs * :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need to do:

1. Create a 2D texture of the maximum size possible for the task, since reallocating textures is an order of magnitude harder than reallocating RAM.
2. Depending on how many channels per texel you need, set the texture type to `GL_RED`, `GL_RG`, `GL_RGB` or `GL_RGBA`. Channel type should certainly be `GL_FLOAT`.
3. Pass the newly created texture to your shader and then update it every time the algorithm requires so.
4. The function that helps update arbitrary rectangular regions in 2D textures is [`glTexSubImage2D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexSubImage2D.xhtml).
5. Also bear in mind that you`d better set magnification mode to `GL_NEAREST`, because otherwise any texture sampling functions except the `texelFetch` family would approximate neighboring colors, which is most probably not what you want.

W.R.T. example code… which language is preferable for you?

Comment: I would prefer javascript. Thank you for help. I also tried something similar to what you said, but maybe I am doing something wrong somewhere, because when I try to get elements stored in the texture, they are not what I expected them to be.

Comment: @MadalinaCi, сan I please look at your code? I\`m almost sure that the root of all your problems is some texture parameter being set incorrectly.

Comment: the question is tagged `WebGL` which means most of your answer doesn't fit

Comment: @gman, doesn\`t WebGL have proper values? It does. Okay, they are named differently (`gl.R32F`, `gl.RG32F`, `gl.RGB32F`, `gl.RGBA32F` to be exact), but this is why I promised to help correcting the code. WebGL does also have texture samplers in shaders, along with `texSubimage`. So, which parts exactly are wrong?

Comment: That's WebGL2 not WebGL. WebGL doesn't have `gl.XX32F` anything. WebGL also doesn't have `textureFetch`, only WebGL2

Comment: Thank you for your comments. And yes, I am a noobie, just started writing in webgl 3 weeks ago. 
@hidefromkgb  I updated the question with some parts of my code, maybe this way it's easier to spot the problems. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @MadalinaCi, sorry for the late answer, I was on a short vacation. The most obvious error I see is `float m1 = texture2D(usampler,vec2(r,ss)).r;` `float m2 = texture2D(usampler,vec2(tt,c)).g;` — row number is actually a vertical coordinate, because every N-th row is below every K-th if K < N; same for column number, it is a horizontal coord. Therefore, `r` and `c` are both misplaced.

Comment: @hidefromkgb you were right! I changed the way I keep the matrices in the texture and the coordonates in the fragment shader for multiplying and now it works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

A texture is just a 2D array of data with 1 to 4 channels. For a matrix you probably want a floating point texture. Floating point texture support is optional but common

```
ext = gl.getExtension("OES_texture_float");
if (!ext) {
   // tell the user they can't run your app
```

So, you put your data in the texture

```
const width = 5;
const height = 5;
const data = new Float32Array(width * height);
data[0] = ???
data[1] = ???
```

etc.

Now make a texture and upload it

```
const tex = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
const level = 0;
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, level, gl.LUMINANCE, width, height 0,
              gl.LUMINANCE, gl.FLOAT, data);
// set the filtering so values don't get mixed
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

`LUMINANCE` is a single channel texture.

To read it you need to know the dimensions in the shader which in WebGL1 you have to pass in yourself

```
uniform vec2 dataTextureSize;
uniform sampler2D dataTexture;
```

Then you can get any element like this

```
float row = ??
float col = ??
vec2 uv = (vec2(col, row) + .5) / dataTextureSize;
float value = texture2D(dataTexture, uv).r;  // just the red channel
```

WebGL doesn't in general let you choose where to write though (that would require compute shaders which is a couple of versions off). So, you either need to structure your app so that you process each destination row and column in order OR there are a few tricks, like using `gl.POINT` and setting `gl_Position` to select a particular output pixel.

You can see [an example of that here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37527102/how-do-you-compute-a-histogram-in-webgl).

If you use [`WebGL2`](http://webgl2fundamentals.org) then you don't need to extension and you can use `texelFetch` to get specific values from the texture.

```
float value = texelFetch(dataTexture, ivec2(col, row));
```

and it might be more appropriate to use `gl.R32F` as your internal format

```
const level = 0;
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, level, gl.R32F, width, height 0,
              gl.RED, gl.FLOAT, data);
```

Comment: [`texelFetch`](https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl2-whats-new.html), not `textureFetch`. See how easy it is to declare an answer wrong?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I wasn't trying to dis your answer but someone who's asking this kind of question likely can not translate between OpenGL and WebGL so it seems like any answer needs to be in WebGL terms.

Comment: @gman I updated the question with some parts of my code. Can you please, take a look and tell me what I do wrong?